# Product of a linear function of IDD variables

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

if $r_i$ are IID variables with $E[r_i]=μ$ and $f$ is a constant, is the following correct?

$E\left[\prod_{i=1}^n(1+f\space r_i)\right] =
\prod_{i=1}^nE\left[1+f\space r_i\right] = 
\prod_{i=1}^n(1+f\space μ) =
(1+f\space μ)^n$

thanks! ‍♂️

Comment: You didn't define f.

Comment: @hstamper ok done 

Comment: The answer to your previous question already confirms it.

Comment: @whuber but that was a non-linear function, so the result should be different - right? that's why I asked two separate questions.

Comment: Independence gives (1->2), linearity gives (2->3). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity